# How to get next 4 months from current month in an array of month objects [{month:'Jan' id:'1},{month:'Feb', id:'2},...{month:'Dec', id:12}]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I tried array slice but its not giving expected result if starting month is one of the last 3 months of the year.

If current month is November then its should give November to February list

Comment: did you give it a try? please share the codebase and post here where you are stuck at. People will be happy to help you. Thanks

Comment: If code is not there so what?. +1 as I felt the problem is genuine

Comment: @Ramesh if you don't understand why having no code isn't good, perhaps you should read the link and find out.  Hint: it isn't because the problem isn't "genuine".

Comment: You have to use a connected circular linked list that can return to its start after the 12th month or just a function that given an array can determine what month sould be returned

Comment: @Amy - I Disagree that without code the question is not answerable. The answers to this question shows it is possible. The OP is new and don't discourage people for reasons which are trivial.

Comment: @Ramesh OK, you're okay with lower quality questions than I am. Maybe, you do things how you see fit, and I'll continue to try improving the quality of questions. That seems fair. If you want to discuss this further, I suggest opening a meta post. I won't discuss this further here.

Answer (score 2):

Simply double the array and then slice it

```
var newArr = [ ...arr, ...arr ];
var index = 10;
var output = newArr.slice( index, index + 4 )
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
  month: 'Jan',
  id: "1"
}, {
  month: 'Feb',
  id: "2"
}, {
  month: 'Mar',
  id: "3"
}, {
  month: 'Apr',
  id: "4"
}, {
  month: 'May',
  id: "5"
}, {
  month: 'Jun',
  id: "6"
}, {
  month: 'Jul',
  id: "7"
}, {
  month: 'Aug',
  id: "8"
}, {
  month: 'Sep',
  id: "9"
}, {
  month: 'Oct',
  id: "10"
}, {
  month: 'Nov',
  id: "11"
}, {
  month: 'Dec',
  id: "12"
}];

var newArr = [ ...arr, ...arr ];
//console.log( newArr );
var index = 10;
var output = newArr.slice(index, index+4);

console.log( output );
```

If spread `...` is not supported, then use `concat`

```
var newArr = arr.concat(arr.slice())
```

Comment: Oh, nice idea.
I was thinking of using modulo, but yours is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

A lengthy approach but works.

```js
let months = ['Jan','Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May' ,'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']


let currMonth_id = new Date().getMonth();

let output = [];
output.push({month: months[currMonth_id], id: currMonth_id+1});

for(let i = 1 ; i < 4; i++) {
  let nextMonth_id = (currMonth_id + i) % 12; 
  output.push({month: months[nextMonth_id], id: nextMonth_id+1});
}

console.log(output)
```